# Support for Scala Enumeration by net.liftweb.json

Tags: scala, enumeration, lift-json

I am using the liftweb JSON converter and got it working, by including the  dependency in `build.sbt` like this:

```
"net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.6.2"
```

This all works before I added Enumerations.
I can see [here](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json) that Enumerations are supported, and you should do something like this:

```
// Scala enums
implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats + new EnumSerializer(MyEnum)
```

But the problem is in my environment the `net.liftweb.json.ext` package is not recognized. This is the package where `EnumSerializer` lives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a separate extensions lib that you would need to include. Adding an extra line something like:

```
"net.liftweb" %% "lift-json-ext" % "2.6.2"
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had an enumeration that was created by the gRPC proto and in that case the EnumSerializer didn't work for me. In that case, I created a custom serializer and worked awesome.

```
case object GrpcTimeUnitSerializer extends CustomSerializer[TimeUnit] (format => (
  {
    case JString(tu) => TimeUnit.fromName(tu.toUpperCase).get
    case JNull       => throw new GrpcServiceException(Status.INTERNAL.withDescription("Not allowed null value for the type TimeUnit."))
  },
  {
    case tu: TimeUnit => JString(tu.toString)
  }
))
```

And here is the `DefaultFormats` definition:

```
implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats + GrpcTimeUnitSerializer
```